# Анимация нод в блендер для юнити 3д

Tags: unity3d, анимация, blender

Сделал икосферу в блендер, к ней сделал ноды, которые в зависимости от кадра меняют эту икосферу, и не понимаю как сделать так, что бы вкладка Animation сохраняла изменения объекта по нодам. Пытался загуглить и даже спросить у чат gpt, но нашел только старый аддон для блендера, который в новых версиях отказывается запускаться. Blender 3.6.4.
Прилагаю фотки нод. и объекта[image: Ноды]
[image: Объект]

Answer (score 0):

Ноды никак нельзя перенести в Unity. По уму вам нужно идти в Unity создавать в шейдерграфе ноды на vertex шейдер. Вот к примеру такой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть конечно walkaround типа переносить анимацию через alembic или запечь в шейпкеи, но вы этим просто убьете перфоманс